# Issue with Books on MediaWiki

Tags: php, python, pdf, collections, mediawiki

I am trying to get a MediaWiki to export to PDF format using the Books/Collection, but it has issues rendering.

I found this useful [article](http://www.speedron.com/blog/software/configuration-of-mediawiki-pdf-writer-extansion-with-mwlib-plugin-on-debianubuntumint/) which is very good, but when I get to:

> $ mw-render --config http:/.localhost/ --username='user' --password='password' --output /path/file.pdf --writer rl

I get an issue. I stick my user name and password in, change the path, but I get the following error:

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mwlib/ext/reportlab/pdfbase/pdfmetrics.py:35: UserWarning: pyfribidi is not installed - RTL not supported
  warnings.warn('pyfribidi is not installed - RTL not supported')
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mwlib/ext/reportlab/pdfgen/textobject.py:23: UserWarning: pyfribidi is not installed - RTL not supported
  warnings.warn('pyfribidi is not installed - RTL not supported')
MISSING FONTS: 'AR PL UMing HK','Nazli','UnBatang','Arundina Serif','Lohit Telugu','Sarai','Gujarati','Lohit Punjabi','Lohit Oriya','AnjaliOldLipi','Kedage','LikhanNormal','Lohit Tamil','Khmer'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/mw-render", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('mwlib==0.15.14', 'console_scripts', 'mw-render')()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mwlib-0.15.14-py2.7-linux-i686.egg/mwlib/apps/render.py", line 243, in main
    return Main()()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mwlib-0.15.14-py2.7-linux-i686.egg/mwlib/apps/render.py", line 194, in __call__
    env = self.get_environment()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mwlib-0.15.14-py2.7-linux-i686.egg/mwlib/apps/render.py", line 120, in get_environment
    env = self.parser.makewiki()        
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mwlib-0.15.14-py2.7-linux-i686.egg/mwlib/options.py", line 114, in makewiki
    env = wiki.makewiki(**kw)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mwlib-0.15.14-py2.7-linux-i686.egg/mwlib/wiki.py", line 213, in makewiki
    res = _makewiki(config, metabook=metabook, **kw)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mwlib-0.15.14-py2.7-linux-i686.egg/mwlib/wiki.py", line 187, in _makewiki
    raise RuntimeError("could not read config file %r" % (conf,))
RuntimeError: could not read config file u'http:localhost/'
```

Anyone know what the issue is?

Answer (score 2):

If anyone's having issues with the "coros" module not being found by mwlib, downgrading the gevent library helps. The coros module has been deprecated and later removed in newer versions.

I'm not sure which is the latest gevent version that has the coros module, but the following resolved the issue for me:

```
pip install gevent==1.1
```

This downgrades gevent library to version 1.1. Version 1.0 does not work because of PROTOCOL_SSLv3.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
mw-render --config **http://localhost/** --username='user' --password='password' --output /path/file.pdf --writer rl
```

Comment: Hmm, not sure why I missed that. But it is still coming up with an error, albeit a different one. I am now getting:

`result = _import(*args, **kwargs)
ImportError: No module named coros`

Comment: I have tried to install coros using pip install coros, but it says it can't be found.

Comment: Install latest gevent python package ,

Comment: Apologies for the delay, I went away with no internet access. I have just tried to install gevent, it says it is already installed.

Comment: @Bob pip install coros --upgrade

Comment: I have just run that and I got this:

Bob-AMILO-Pi-1505 maintenance # cd
Bob-AMILO-Pi-1505 ~ # pip install coros --upgrade
Downloading/unpacking coros
  Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement coros
Cleaning up...
No distributions at all found for coros
Storing debug log for failure in /root/.pip/pip.log